# Why the Meteor package ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3 is behaving differently if is installed as a dependency?

Tags: meteor, dependencies, package

I'm trying to create a Meteor package, which has, as a dependency the package ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3. I added the dependency in my package.js like this:

```
Package.onUse(function(api) {
  api.versionsFrom('1.1.0.2');
  api.use(['ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3'], 'client');
 api.addFiles('package-name.js');
});
```

After I add my package in the console, the following packages are added to the project:

```
accounts-base                added, version 1.2.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
me:my-package-name           added, version 0.0.1                                                                                                                                                    
handlebars                   added, version 1.0.3                                                                                                                                                    
ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3  added, version 1.0.7                                                                                                                                                    
localstorage                 added, version 1.0.3                                                                                                                                                    
service-configuration        added, version 1.0.4                                                                                                                                                    
stylus                       added, version 1.0.7
```

The issue is that the accounts system is not working. In the browser I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

'push' being the property of

```
Template.__body__.__contentParts
```

If I add the ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3 manually it works fine, I don't get the error. But when I do that, the packages which are installed on the project are a little different:

```
accounts-base                added, version 1.2.0                                                                                                                                                    
anti:i18n                    added, version 0.4.3                                                                                                                                                    
ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3  added, version 1.2.59                                                                                                                                                   
localstorage                 added, version 1.0.3                                                                                                                                                    
service-configuration        added, version 1.0.4                                                                                                                                                    
stylus                       added, version 1.0.7
```

As you can see I don't have handlebars anymore but instead anti:i18n. I tried to install the anti:i18n as a dependency in my package but I got the same browser error.

Can anyone say, what I'm doing wrong and why the package behaves like that when is installed differently (manual vs dependency).
To give you this example I just created an empty package, with only this dependency, so nothing else can affect the number of packages being installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. When installed as a dependency the package: ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3 will install version 1.0.7 which is an old one.
When it is installed manually, it installs version 1.2.59 and this one has the features I want.
So to solve the issue I just specified the needed version in the dependency using '@'.

I think this have to be changed, like when you install a package via a dependency, it should install the latest version and an older one only if is specified by @.

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'imply' instead of 'use'. This exposes the package to the global scope. Without much more in details of your problem this is probably most likely to solve the issue (I hope):

```
api.imply(['ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3']);
```

Instead of

```
api.use(['ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3'], 'client');
```

Comment: I tried that, but I got the same error unfortunately.

Comment: @BogdanLungu What file does the issue come from? It looks like a loading order issue

Comment: The files that generate the error are: login_buttons_dialogs.html and ian_accounts-ui-bootstrap-3.js